# list of dictionary search

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.4

I have a list of dictionaries as follows

```
list1 = [{'3': ['0'], '10': ['2'], '9': ['8'], '6': ['8']},
         {'3': ['5'], '9': ['0'], '2': ['3']},
         {'2':['10'],'10':['8'],'4' :['9']}]
```

and I have another list as

```
list2 = [0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want to check for each value of `list2` whether its a key of any dictionary of `list1` and then if it matches with keys then I want all the values associate with those keys and add those values. How can I achieve this in python in a very optimized way as my list of dictionary is really large.

Comment: Also, clarify what the output you expect is, maybe for the example you have given.

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(list)
for x in list1:
    for y,z in x.items():
        dct[int(y)].append(int(z[0]))
for x in list2:
    if x in dct:
        print sum(dct[x])
```

Comment: Thank you so much anand. the only problem i am getting in this approach is that if the key is more than one digit number(say 11,111,99,9999),it coping the key value as the first digit,instead of the actual value.how do i resolve this?

Comment: Fixed it. Indexed the key unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

Because your list of dictionaries is really large, a preprocessing is necessary and effective.

```
SumKey = {}
for item in list1:
    for key in item.keys():
        if key not in SumKey:
            SumKey[key] = 0
        SumKey[key] += item[key]

SumList = []
for item in list2:
    if item in SumKey.keys():
        SumList.append(SumKey[item])
    else:
        SumList.append(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are very pythonic, and might be a little obtuse.

This is a little more readable (but not the most performant!):

```
list1=[{'3': ['0'], '10': ['2'], '9': ['8'], '6': ['8']},\
       {'3': ['5'], '9': ['0'], '2': ['3']},\
       {'2':['10'],'10':['8'],'4' :['9']}]

list2 = [0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10]
strlist2 = [str(x) for x in list2]

total = 0
for subdict in list1:
    filtered = [v for k, v in subdict.items() if k in strlist2]

    print(filtered)

    for sublist in filtered:
        print(sublist)

        for val in sublist:
            total += int(val)

print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
opDict = {}
for key in list2:
    opDict[str(key)] = 0

for elem in list2:
    for dictElem in list1:
        if str(elem) in dictElem:
            opDict[str(elem)] += int(dictElem[str(elem)][0])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: yes @JeenBroekstra is right. Try adding some textual comments with the answer to further simplify it.